# Internet Explorer blocked by Defender Controlled Folder access - what is %desktopdirectory%\瘁毓翹?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender, security-warning, controlled-folder-access

I (accidently) launched Internet Explorer today and this triggered the following alert in Windows Defender (copy from the windows event log `Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational`):

```
C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe was blocked by controlled folder access to change the path %desktopdirectory%\瘁毓翹.
    Detection Time: 2018-07-05T19:07:47.684Z
    Path: %desktopdirectory%\瘁毓翹
    Process Name: C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe
    Signature Version: 1.271.495.0
    Module Version: 1.1.15000.2
    Product Version: 4.18.1806.18062
```

While other people seem to have the same problem, I found no explanation what `iexplore.exe` is trying to do there. Any ideas? Should I be worried about malware?

And: I won't whitelist `iexplore.exe` because I don't use it and I find that path suspicious.

Comment: `ver` says: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112]`

Comment: Did you enable `Controlled Folder Access` on your desktop directory on purpose?  An English translation would be appreciated.  The non-English characters should be removed (since they are not appearing correctly anyways).

Comment: I activated it some time ago and after I whitelisted several known applications which I and trust didn't find it problematic. I translated the log message from german to english.

Comment: "瘁毓翹" is from the error message or is it being introduced by something else?

Comment: It is from the error message - and I've a german windows localization!

Comment: Well `瘁毓翹` isn't german.  It also has nothing to do with your locale.  IE is trying to access a file or folder on your desktop.  If you create a new user profile, does the behavior, exhibit itself?  I have identified a thread, surrounding this exact same warning with IE, so the problem isn't unique to 1803.  However, the Chinese characters were not identical.  So is there perhaps a hidden folder on your desktop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79816/discussion-between-ramhound-and-ventiseis).